# Nlog does not write to log file in windows service

Tags: c#, windows-services, nlog

I have a windows service written in .net 4.0 and I installed it under credential of Local System. In the code I used nlog,

```
private static Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
logger.Debug("some information");
```

I also have nlog.config copied to the same directory where exe file resides

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <targets>
    <target name="logfile" type="File"
            fileName="c:\log\TestService\My.log"
            layout="${longdate}::${logger}::${message}"
            keepFileOpen="false" />
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" maxLevel="Deubg" writeTo="logfile" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

But if I start the service, I don't see the log file has been created at all. If I swap the `log.Debug` code to `Debug.WriteLine` and use my Visual Studio to attach to the windows service process to debug, I can see the output window has my debugging message, which means my windows service code is correct.

Is there any problem with my nlog code?

-- **Update 1** --

I updated nlog.config to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <targets>
    <target name="logfile" type="File"
            fileName="c:\log\TestService\My.log"
            layout="${longdate}::${logger}::${message}"
            keepFileOpen="false" />
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="logfile" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

and changed my code to

```
logger.Trace("some information");
```

then it works. I am not sure what is wrong with my first set of configuration.

Comment: I'd guess that LocalSystem doesn't have write permission to that folder.

Comment: at first sight i would say your target-tag should look something like this:

`<target name="logfile" xsi:type="File"
            fileName="C:/log/TestService/My.log"
            layout="${longdate}::${logger}::${message}"
            keepFileOpen="false" />`

otherwise: you have a standalone NLog.config file, right? if so it might not be built (in your /bin directory) --> so the service will not find the config it needs! have a look [here](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Logging-Troubleshooting)

Comment: @Matt see my updated question above, I don't quite understand what makes difference between debug and trace.

Comment: just to be sure: did you recognise the misspelling in your first attempt? where `<logger name="*" minlevel="Info" maxLevel="Deubg" writeTo="logfile" />` should actually say `maxLevel="Debug"`?

Comment: @Matt, nice catch!! this might be the problem.

Comment: From https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Log-levels - Trace log level is BELOW Info log level.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**UPDATE**

```
<logger name="*" minlevel="Info" maxLevel="Deubg" writeTo="logfile" />
                                           ^^^^^
```

**First of all: `Debug` is spelled wrong.**

But the main problem is that the **Debug level is under the info level**.

The following are the allowed log levels (in descending order):

- off
- fatal
- error
- warn
- info
- debug
- trace (Most detailed information.)

[Link to the nlog documentation](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Log-levels)

Comment: for deeper understanding when to use which log level see [nlog documentation](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Tutorial#log-levels) too

Comment: "Frist of all: debug is spelled wrong." - if transposing the characters in first when pointing out that characters in debug are transposed was deliberate, brilliant and clever.